# why can't I use @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] outside a route?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

why cannot I use `@env['REMOTE_ADDR']` outside a route in Sinatra?

I want to have client's ip available for my whole Sinatra application so I can use it anywhere ...

```
 clients_ip = @env['REMOTE_ADDR']

  get '/' do
     .. show something ..
     clients_ip
  end
  get '/page1' do
    .. show something ..
    clients_ip
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the route blocks run in response to a request. The code outside is run once when the handler is set up.

Instead of using a variable you can do what you want with a method, this makes sure that the lookup in `@env` is done in the correct scope.

```
def clients_ip
  @env['REMOTE_ADDR']
end

get '/' do
  # ... show something ...
  clients_ip
end
```

Comment: ok, and how can I define `  growl = Growl.new(@env['REMOTE_ADDR'], "ruby-growl", ["ruby-growl Notification"])` so I can use it in any route?

Comment: Do it the same way: `def growl; Growl.new(...); end`

Comment: it's bit out of my thinking...classes, classes, classes.... let me try how it works....

Comment: I guess I want only one instance of growl for the same ip (client). Do I have to take care about it or ... ?

Comment: If you want to cache the `Growl` instances you can do `def growl; @growl_cache ||= {}; @growl_cache[@env['REMOTE_ADDR']] = Growl.new(...); end`, but this cache will never get emptied, so eventually (with enough clients) you will run out of memory, so I don't recommend it. You would have to periodically empty the cache somehow.